# poorly rendered/antialased canvas text on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, text, canvas, fonts

The text comes out looking pixelated / aliased (firefox and opera)

As it seems like there's not much to do about the actual issue, are there any quirks/tricks that might reduce this effect?

Thanks
/A

```
context.textBaseline = 'top'
context.fillStyle = color
context.font = "16px gotham_htfregular"
context.fillText("HD", 15, 11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help, but it helped me with Anti-aliased edges on images within the `canvas`:

```
                canvas {
                  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
                  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
                  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
                  image-rendering: optimize-contrast;
                  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}
```

**note**: that the `-ms-interpolation-mode` is for IE, but included for good measure.